# Time travel book where bacteria heated to a specific degree causes plague

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

All I remember of the book is a man goes into the future, learns that heating bacteria to a certain temperature degree will cause plague/sickness/airborne danger something. He goes back in time to warn everyone, but his warning is what causes government/scientists to learn to heat to that degree, so he's the cause of it and if he didn't warn everyone it wouldn't have happened. So he goes to an in between world? Or something similar, and eats fruit from a tree to stay in a coma like state to ignore what he caused.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.   When did you read this?  Do you recall the cover art?

Comment: I had thought it was Divide, but upon looking it it up its not so maybe the title is similar, I don't remember the cover art. I read it in 2017-2018